# CSS rotation problem found when execute it in edge

Tags: css, angular, rotation, microsoft-edge

I wrote some pieces of codes in angular about rotating an icon by pressing a toggle button in angular.
When I run it in chrome everything is OK but in Edge rotation process works properly but final rotation status is 180 degree reverse.

Here is my snippets:

my `.ts` file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-menutest',
  templateUrl: './menutest.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menutest.component.scss']
})
export class MenutestComponent implements OnInit {
  public classChangesRotation: {[key: string]: string} = {};
  public expandeds: {[key: string]: boolean} = {};
  private zero: string;

  constructor() {
    this.zero = 'zero';
    this.expandeds[this.zero] = true;
    this.classChangesRotation[this.zero] = 'rotate-expanded';
  }

  expansion_click(divName: string) {
    this.expandeds[divName] = !this.expandeds[divName];
    if (this.expandeds[divName]) {
      this.classChangesRotation[divName] = 'rotate-expanded';
    } else {
      this.classChangesRotation[divName] = 'rotate-collapsed';
    }
  }
}
```

my `html` file:

```
<button mat-raised-button (click)="expansion_click('zero')">
  Expand and Collapse
  <mat-icon [ngClass]="classChangesRotation['zero']">
    chevron_left
  </mat-icon>
</button>
```

and my `scss` file contains :

```
.rotate-expanded {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    transition: -webkit-transform 150ms;
    transition: transform 150ms;
    transition: transform 150ms,-webkit-transform 150ms;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.rotate-collapsed {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
    transform: rotate(0);
    transition: -webkit-transform 150ms;
    transition: transform 150ms;
    transition: transform 150ms,-webkit-transform 150ms;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

As I mentioned above when I run these codes in chrome everything is OK and normal but in Edge the animation process is fine but final rotation differs 180 degrees!

Do you have any idea?

Thank you for your attentions.

Pay attention please:

> You should know that direction of this code is right to left and result in LTR direction is OK but the problem is in RTL direction. I understand it right now and added it to my question.

Comment: transform: rotate() is used for rotating the element. I made a test with it and looks like it is working fine MS Edge browser. You can refer to this example. https://codepen.io/colewaldrip/pen/bdZVGd I suggest you create a new sample example just using CSS and HTML and try to run it in the Edge browser. It can help to narrow down the issue. Let us know about your testing result.

Comment: If you notice to last paragraph of my question I told you that it's OK with LTR direction but my code is written under RTL direction and it made my animation result mistake.

Comment: I suggest you refer to this example. It is working fine with the Edge browser. Ref: http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/ERRmd/